# Nginx location domain.ltd regex

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, location

i need rewrite for domain whois for example `http://domainname.ltd/example.com` must be call `http://domainname.ltd/whois.php?d=example.com`

i try location examples but not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.com;

  location = /whois.php {
    proxy_pass http://your_origin_host.com
  }

  location ~ \/(.*) {
    set $domain_query $1;
    set $args "d=${domain_query}";
    rewrite ^ /whois.php last;
  }
}
```